# Are questions about the start point for a future career in bio-informatics on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am a math undergrad student and I'm highly interested in applications of mathematics to biology, medicine and health issues. However, my knowledge about bioinformatics is very limited. I did take a course offered on coursera about genomic sequences but that's all. I scored 100% on that course because I really found the subject fascinating. So, I was thinking that maybe I could spend more time on this website and become a bio-mathematician or at least learn whether this is something I want to do as a career in future or not.

So, I searched through the tags, looking for a tag for my question but didn't find the "soft-question" tag or any tag that fit my question. So, I decided to ask a question on meta to know whether this newly-established community welcomes questions of the kind I described. :)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what kind of questions you'd be asking. Could you give a more specific example? I am afraid you might well be right and this won't be the best place for them, but I can't really tell from your description.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about career choices are subjective and open for discussion, which is a format that doesn't work well for Stack Exchange. I'd recommend posting the question on the Bioinformatics [subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/bioinformatics).